# Fragment から別の Fragment に画面遷移をKotlinで実行するときのエラー

Tags: java, android, kotlin

### 実行したいこと

Fragment から別の Fragment に画面遷移をしようとしています。

[[Android] Fragment から別の Fragment に画面遷移させてみる](https://akira-watson.com/android/fragment-fragment.html)という記事を参考にしていますが、Javaで書かれているので自動翻訳でKotlinにするとエラーが起きて解決方法がわかりません。

### エラーメッセージ

これらのエラーをどうしたら解決できるのかわからず、困っています。

MainActivity.kt

```
Unresolved reference:activity_main
Unresolved reference:container
```

Fragment01.kt

```
Unresolved reference:fragment01
Unresolved reference:textview_01
Unresolved reference:button_01
Unresolved reference:container
Unresolved reference:pop_01
```

Fragment02.kt

```
Unresolved reference:fragment02
Unresolved reference:textview_02
Unresolved reference:button_02
Unresolved reference:container
Unresolved reference:pop_02
```

### コード

layoutとvaluesはそのまま[[Android] Fragment から別の Fragment に画面遷移させてみる](https://akira-watson.com/android/fragment-fragment.html)のコードを実行しています。

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.fragfrag

import android.R
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
            val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

            // BackStackを設定
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)

            // counterをパラメータとして設定
            val count = 0
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, Fragment01.newInstance(count))

            fragmentTransaction.commit()
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment01.kt

```
package com.example.fragfrag

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction

import android.R
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView

class Fragment01 : Fragment() {

    private var cnt = 0

    // FragmentのViewを生成して返す
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment01,
            container, false
        )
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val args = arguments

        if (args != null) {
            val count = args.getInt("Counter")
            val str = "Fragment01: $count"
            cnt = count + 1

            val textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textview_01)
            textView.setText(str)
        }

        val button01 = view.findViewById(R.id.button_01)
        button01.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val fragmentManager = fragmentManager

            if (fragmentManager != null) {
                val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                // BackStackを設定
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, Fragment02.newInstance(cnt))
                fragmentTransaction.commit()
            }
        })

        // BackStackで１つ戻す
        val pop01 = view.findViewById(R.id.pop_01)
        pop01.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val fragmentManager = fragmentManager
            fragmentManager?.popBackStack()
        })
    }

    companion object {

        internal fun newInstance(count: Int): Fragment01 {
            // Fragemnt01 インスタンス生成
            val fragment01 = Fragment01()

            // Bundle にパラメータを設定
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putInt("Counter", count)
            fragment01.arguments = args

            return fragment01
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment02.kt

```
package com.example.fragfrag

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction

import android.R
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView

class Fragment02 : Fragment() {

    private var cnt = 0

    // FragmentのViewを生成して返す
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment02,
            container, false
        )
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val args = arguments

        if (args != null) {
            val count = args.getInt("Counter")
            val str = "Fragment02: $count"
            cnt = count + 1

            val textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textview_02)
            textView.setText(str)
        }

        val button02 = view.findViewById(R.id.button_02)
        button02.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val fragmentManager = fragmentManager
            if (fragmentManager != null) {
                val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

                // BackStackを設定
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, Fragment01.newInstance(cnt))
                fragmentTransaction.commit()
            }
        })

        // BackStackで１つ戻す
        val pop02 = view.findViewById(R.id.pop_02)
        pop02.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val fragmentManager = fragmentManager
            fragmentManager?.popBackStack()
        })
    }

    companion object {

        internal fun newInstance(count: Int): Fragment02 {
            // Fragemnt02 インスタンス生成
            val fragment02 = Fragment02()

            // Bundleにパラメータを設定
            val barg = Bundle()
            barg.putInt("Counter", count)
            fragment02.arguments = barg

            return fragment02
        }
    }
}
```

### ご回答を受けて試したこと

各ktファイルの　`import android.R`を削除しました。

- 記事では後段にリソースファイルがありますが、これらはプロジェクトに読み込まれていますか?
- その場合、最後のファイルは記事内ではstrngs.xmlとなっていますが正しくはstrings.xmlとなります。正しく配備されていますか?

これらの２点も確認しました。

エラーが以下のように変わりました。

Fragment01.ktとFragment02.ktで`findViewById`がエラーになります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんにちは。はじめまして。

エラーの内容はリソースファイルの読み込みエラーです。

Unresolved Reference = 未解決の参照

ですので、各ktファイルの`import android.R`を削除して、
プロジェクトで動的生成されるパッケージのRファイルをimportするようにしてください。

また以下の点も確認してください

- 記事では後段にリソースファイルがありますが、これらはプロジェクトに読み込まれていますか?
- その場合、最後のファイルは記事内では`strngs.xml`となっていますが正しくは`strings.xml`となります。正しく配備されていますか?

**[追記に対する回答]**
Javaのように変数に型を示していないため、型推論に失敗しているので元コードを見ながら下記のように`<>`で型を指定してあげてください。

```
val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_02)
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。「プロジェクトで動的生成されるパッケージのRファイルをimportする」についてもう少し詳しく教えていただけませんでしょうか。質問に「ご回答を受けて試したこと」として現状を共有させていただきました。

Comment: 回答を追記させていただきました。解決しそうであれば解決へのマークと、回答へのupvoteをお願いします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。stackoveflow信用度の都合で、upvoteはできませんでした。